# Autoit use variable instead of directory name

Tags: java, autoit

I just wonder how to set this up. The user should select a jar file through:

```
    Case $fileitem
        $file = FileOpenDialog("Choose file...", "\", "Jar Files (*.jar*)")
```

Then file in $file should be used in:

```
Run("java " & $chosen &  $file, "", $Hide)
```

The on with $file instead of location gives an error because the directory has spaces. How can I give the variable quotes?
The normal one without the choice is:

```
Run("java " & $chosen & ' -jar spigot-1.6.2-R0.1.jar', "E:\Spill\Alle spill\Minecraft\KnarCraft 2013", $Hide)
```

Also. I write it to a file with:

```
IniWrite("C:\Config.ini", "Server File", "File1", $file)
```

How should I read it so you don't have to choose twice.

Comment: I didn't understand `How should I read it so you don't have to choose twice.`. Can you explain?

Comment: What I mean is that it writes the location to a file: [Server File]
File1=E:\Spill\Alle spill\Minecraft\KnarCraft 2013\spigot-1.6.2-R0.1.jar I need to export that value back on startup. I don't know how to ask for whatever value there are instead of a certain value.

Comment: You mean, you need to "import" that value again? ;-) And it's better to ask one question at a time instead of editing a question to ask for a solution to a second problem. And probably your trial and error code developement is better treated in one of the AutoIt forums? StackOverflow is a question/answer site for specific problems that other developers would have as well. It not the first place to improve your programming skills. This is the fourth or fifth question on your minecraft server topic stumbling over problems not knowing AutoIt very well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
Run('java "' & $chosen & '" "' &  $file & '"', "", $Hide)
```

Comment: It only gives me: Run("java '" & $chosen &  $file, "'", $Hide)
Run("java '" & $chosen &  ^ ERROR

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrote it wrong.. I'll rewrite it. **EDIT:** Done rewriting the `Run` formula.

Comment: The first one gives me the could not find main class error. The second seems to combine $chosen and $file together so the output gets -Xmx512ME\Spill\Alle spill\Minecraft\KnarCraft2013\spigot-1.6.2-R0.1.jar They need to be splitted.

Comment: So, put a space in the second, just as my edit, above. **EDIT:** I removed the first...

Comment: They splitted now and surrounded with double quotes.

Comment: Now this one gives the could not find main class error, but the way it reads it is right. I think the problem is because of the removed -jar from ' -jar spigot-1.6.2-R0.1.jar'. I think it needs it to read it as a file instead of a java class.

Comment: For sure, you need the `-jar` flag to open a program inside of a jar file... And the solution of putting double quotes into strings with single quotes is the right track...